# Google Firebase this.state.posts.map() is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, get, axios

I am retrieving data from google firebase live database using GET from Axios but I receive the error "this.state.posts.map()" As far as I can tell the data I am receiving is in an array so I would expect it to be able to be mapped?

Is the data returning as an array as I think it is or is something else incorrect with it?

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from '../../../axios';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Post from '../../../components/Post/Post';
import './Posts.css';
import FullPost from '../FullPost/FullPost';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

class Posts extends Component {
  state = {
    posts: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    //console.log( this.props );
    axios
      .get(`https://${MY_FIREBASE_DATABASE}.firebaseio.com/posts.json`)
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ posts: response.data });

        const updatedPosts = this.state.posts.map(post => {
          return {
            ...post,
            author: 'Max'
          };
        });
        this.setState({ posts: updatedPosts });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        // this.setState({error: true});
      });
  }

  render() {
    let posts = <p style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Something went wrong!</p>;
    if (!this.state.error) {
      posts = this.state.posts.map(post => {
        return (
          // <Link to={'/posts/' + post.id} key={post.id}>
          <Post
            key={post.id}
            title={post.title}
            author={post.author}
            clicked={() => this.postSelectedHandler(post.id)}
          />
          // </Link>
        );
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you check the type of `response.data` by logging? `console.log(typeof response.data)`

Comment: It was logged as type Object

Comment: then plz check the `response.data` to see if it is array object of posts.

Comment: when I console.log(response.data) I get [object object] so it seems correct?

Comment: can't you check the data of the object? if yes, just try to log `JSON.stringify(response.data)`

Comment: stringify returns 
{"-MP_k_p-P3v5MRfXJ2ka":{"author":"Max","body":"matt","title":"matt"}}

 so it should be creating an array of these objects correct? I thought since posts is an array posts: [{object}, {object}...] it should be able to map these.

Answer (score 2):

1. should update state only once in this case.
2. can not do any assignment while rendering

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from '../../../axios';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Post from '../../../components/Post/Post';
import './Posts.css';
import FullPost from '../FullPost/FullPost';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

class Posts extends Component {
    state = {
        posts: []
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        //console.log( this.props );
        axios.get('https://'MY_FIREBASE_DATABASE'.firebaseio.com/posts.json')
            .then( response => {
                // this.setState( {posts: response.data} ); not needed
                
                const updatedPosts = response.data.posts.map( post => {
                    return {
                        ...post,
                        author: 'Max'
                    }
                } );
                this.setState( { posts: updatedPosts } );
                
            } )
            .catch( error => {
                console.log( error );
                // this.setState({error: true});
            } );
    }

    render () {
        if ( !this.state.error ) {
            this.state.posts.map( post => {
                return (
                    // <Link to={'/posts/' + post.id} key={post.id}>
                    <Post
                        key={post.id}
                        title={post.title}
                        author={post.author}
                        clicked={() => this.postSelectedHandler( post.id )} />
                    // </Link>
                );
            } );
        } else {
          return (<p style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Something went wrong!</p>)
        }
```

Comment: I believe this is working to solve my solution! I am getting a CORS error now resulting in undefined data response but I think that is another issue.

Comment: yup. let me know if this does not work post CORS issue fixed.